# Do snowshoe and hailstorm spammers use auto-generated domain names?

Tags: spam

My question is about snowshoe and hailstorm spam emails. Do snowshoe and hailstorm spammers use auto-generated domain names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of them almost certainly do.  I don't have a specific example to hand, but I have seen spam campaigns where the domains were made of several words, and often had the same words in different domains, leading me to believe that they were using a (relatively short) wordlist to generate the domains used for spamming.